# My Huawei Ascend Y530 couldn't save screenshot or download or upload pictures in whatsapp

Tags: huawei-ascend-ii

Please help me my Huawei Ascend Y530 couldn't capture and save screenshot. It keep telling me that "storage may be in use". I tried to change a SD memory card (from 2Gb to 8GB) but the problem persist. Also the device can not download or upload pictures in whats app. I tried restore factory but the problem persist.

What should I do?